# How can you multithread an html parser [ in C++ and similar languages ]?

Tags: c++, performance, multithreading, html, parsing

Ive done two HTML parsers.

1. Done with Regular Expressions [that accounted for nesting]. It was quick, but error prone.
2. Done by evaluating Character by Character through switches. Here was the basic structure:

---

> 1. Evaluate html character by character, beginning to end.
> 2. Characters are fed through through various switches, and are buffered then paired off with enumerated components.

```cpp
        } case QCD::Declaration: {
            // <!DOCTYPE foo>
            //  : OpeningBracket : <
            //  : Declaration    : !
            //  : Label          : DOCTYPE
            //  : Delimiter      :
            //  : Parameter      : html
            //  : ClosingBracket : >
```

> 3. Pairs are evaluated, and construct special strings with parsing information.

---

My second iteration is stable, easy to debug, able to correct badly formed html, but not terribly fast.
If I could multithread it, that would be great. I can't think of how you could do this however, considering the problem of finding closing tags.
Was my second parser the right approach or are there multithreading strategies?

The only thing I can think of improving my second approach, is to open up another thread, that will evaluate the html backwards, and meeting in the middle.

Comment: Parsing is a very well known computer science topic. Why not go through the normal lexing/parsing/ast sort of process?

Comment: @Telastyn I'm self taught; the big drawback for that is that I don't know what I don't know.

Comment: So am I, but the Internet has lots of info.

Comment: What makes you so sure that more threads will make this faster?  Even with today's high core count processors, parsing an HTML document is done in milliseconds.  Adding threads and synchronization issues overcomplicates things and will likely take longer.  Unless you are dealing in HTML files that are GB in size, I doubt you'll see the improvements you are expecting.

Comment: Parsing HTML *cannot* be multithreaded because the interpretation of one character depends on all previous characters in the document. This data dependency could only be sidestepped by speculative parsing. Modern browsers already do some amount of speculation, for example to continue parsing beyond a `<script>` block even though the script may modify the document source via `document.write()`. The HTML parsing algorithm is defined in terms of individual characters (read the WhatWG spec), so a separate lexer does not help.

Comment: Did you profile your parser's runtime behaviour? You might find a most-innocent place where your implementation spends its time and can be improved by a significant factor. This often happened to me.